# If R is a relation, then what is $R^0$?

Tags: relations

I'm sorry if this seems like a question asked before doing any research, but the discrete math textbook I'm using doesn't mention it, and I tried googling it, but I don't even know the name of it, so I couldn't find anything either.

The original question is: Let A be a set and R $\subseteq A \times A$ be a binary relation on A. Prove that R is reflexive $\Leftarrow\Rightarrow R^0\subseteq R$

**I would just like to know what $R^0$ means here.**

Comment: Maybe $\{(x,x), x\in A\}$...

Comment: @Augustin that was my first guess too. But it'd be strange if it were denote $R^0$ as it has not relation to $R$.

Comment: No but it's still a relation. Actually it's the smallest reflexive relation.

Comment: If the exponent is composition, then $R^0$ should be the identity, which I would expect to be the diagonal.

Comment: Well, it is true that a relation $R$ is reflexive if and only if $\Delta:=\{(x,x)\ :\ x\in A\}\subseteq R$, so it makes sense for it to mean that. Also, it is true that $\Delta\circ R=R\circ\Delta=R=R^{1+0}$.

Comment: Well I guess that makes sense.

Comment: I did not think of that meaning of the exponent. That is indeed a plausible explanation.

Comment: @GEdgar The book containing the question contains only practice problems. The textbook I'm referring to is Discrete Mathematics And Its Application by K. H. Rosen. So I assume it's just a weird (uncommon) notation.

Comment: So, I guess there is a book by Rosen, which contains this definition, but you have only the practice problems for the book?